# django-registration and user profile creation

Tags: django

In my app i have the `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` set to `users.UserProfile`. This UserProfile has a function `create` which should be called, when a new user registers, and then create the UserProfile entry.

According to the django-registration documentation all in need to do is setting the `profile_callback` entry in my urls.py. Mine looks like this:

```
url(r'^register/$', register, {'form_class': RecaptchaRegistrationForm,
'profile_callback': UserProfile.objects.create,
'backend': 'registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend',},
 name='registration_register')
```

but I get this error:

> Exception Value: register() got an unexpected keyword argument 'profile_callback'

So where do I have to put this, to make it work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Which version of django-registration are you using ? And which version of the django-registration are you referring to ? I didn't know about this profile_callback.

Another way to achieve what you're looking for is to use Django signals (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/). The django-registration application provides some.

A way to achieve that is to create an signals.py in your project (or application) and connected to signals like the documentation said. Then import the signals module into your **init**.py or urls.py file to be sure it'll be read when your project is run.

The following example is done using the post_save signals but you may want to use the django-registration provided ones.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from userprofile.models import UserProfile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def createUserProfile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """Create a UserProfile object each time a User is created ; and link it.
    """
    UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(createUserProfile, sender=User)
```

Comment: looks like I used a new django-registration version and read old documentation. I just found this in the commit messages:

"Custom signals are now sent on user registration and user activation. The profile_callback mechanism which previously served a similar purpose has been removed, so this is backwards-incompatible."

So your solution is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Django-registration provides two signals, which are:

- user_registered : Sent when registration is complete
- user_activated : Sent when user has activated his account using the activation link

For your case, you need user_registered

```
from registration.signals import user_registered
def createUserProfile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    user_profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

user_registered.connect(createUserProfile)
```

You don't need to create any separate signals.py file. You can keep this code in models.py of any of your app. However, since its Profile creation code, you should keep it in profiles/models.py