# In Django Extending User Form for Custom User

Tags: python, django

I extended my User Model as described in this SO Posting:
[Extending the User model with custom fields in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109/extending-the-user-model-with-custom-fields-in-django)

However, I'm trying to create a User Create form but I get the following:

'Members' object has no attribute 'set_password'

Here is my model form:

```
class Members(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

GENDER_CHOICES = ( ... )
gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
date_of_birth     = models.DateField()
class Meta:
    db_table='members'

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Members.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

....and my form....

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    GENDER_CHOICES = ( ... )
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email address', max_length=75)
    first_name   = forms.CharField(label='First Name')
    last_name    = forms.CharField(label='Last Name')
    gender  = forms.ChoiceField(widget=RadioSelect, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    date_of_birth = forms.DateField(initial=datetime.date.today)

    class Meta:
        model = Members
        fields = ('username', 'email','first_name', 'last_name')
```

I'm new at Django,so thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you chose to extend your `User` model is by creating a `UserProfile` (which you've called `Member`). A `Member` is **not** a subclass of `User`, so you can't call `User` methods (like `set_password`) on it.

Instead, your SignUpForm's Meta model should still be User, and to get the extended UserProfile, you should call user.get_profile(). For instance, to get a user's gender, you would call `user.get_profile().gender`.

Read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users for more information about extending the user profile.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Do I override the form object's save parameter, do user.get_profile() then save the new userprofile object?  (I renamed Member to UserProfile)

Comment: There's a [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727564/how-to-create-a-userprofile-form-in-django-with-first-name-last-name-modificati) that might help you out. That solution has you overriding ``save()``. I've never written anything that had to use a UserProfile (all my projects extend the User class), so I'm afraid I can't help you too much more.

Comment: Note that get_profile has been deprecated since django 1.5 and removed in 1.7