# Expanding UserCreationForm for customized Django registration

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to understand how to expand the CreationForm library to utilize some custom fields I have in another model. Basically, in my model, I have a field called codeid and my goal is to have the user type in an integer and have that store into the database as they register. I know I'm somewhat on the right track, but there is some flawed logic behind my current code.

## Forms.py

```
from django import forms            
from django.contrib.auth.models import User   # fill in custom user info then save it 
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm      
from .models import Address, Job

class MyRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(required = True)
    #udid = forms.CharField(required = True)

    class Meta:
        model = Address

        fields = ('username', 'codeid', )        

    def save(self,commit = True):   
        user = super(MyRegistrationForm, self).save(commit = False)
        user.codeid = self.cleaned_data['codeid']

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return
```

## Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect    
from django.contrib import auth                 
from django.core.context_processors import csrf 
from forms import MyRegistrationForm

def register_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyRegistrationForm(request.POST)     # create form object
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form'] = MyRegistrationForm()
    print args
    return render(request, 'register.html', args)
```

## Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Address(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    street_address = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    state = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    zipcode = models.IntegerField(max_length = 5)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True, auto_now_add = False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = False, auto_now_add = True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    codeid = models.IntegerField(max_length = 10, default = 0)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profiles/', default="")

    def __str__(self,):
        return 'test'
```

## Registration HTML

```
{% extends 'home.html' %}

{%block content %}


<h2>Register</h2>
<form action='/register/' method = "post">  {% csrf_token %}

{{ form }}

<input type = "submit" value = "Register" />

</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: My Error: 'Address' object has no attribute 'set_password'

Answer (score 0):

Make change in forms.py :
   return user

Comment: That doesn't do it because I'm getting 'Address' object has no attribute 'set_password'

Comment: in your registration form are you asking for password or not?

Comment: Everything I am using is provided above. The password is automatically generated from the CreationForm library.

Comment: The object model doesn't contain a set_password field, though. I feel like it's mixing up the User with the Address model

Comment: I think you should have in your forms.py in class Meta in fields password1 and password2

Comment: still raising: 'Address' object has no attribute 'set_password'

Comment: See this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441956/in-django-extending-user-form-for-custom-user