# django adding fields to model form

Tags: django, django-forms

Following is the model which I have

```
class OrgStaff(BaseModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    member_type = models.BooleanField(help_text="1. Read/Write 0. Read Only")
    task = models.ForeignKey(ToDos, null=True, blank=True)
    org = models.ForeignKey(Org)
    # TODO Add possible activities

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Following is the forms file

```
class AddStaffForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = OrgStaff
        exclude = (
            'task',
            'org'
            )
```

and this is how I process the view

```
if request.POST and form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    ret_url = reverse("some_view", kwargs={
            'var':var,})
    return redirect(ret_url)
return render(request, "form.html", {"form":form})
```

This form would render a dropdown, which will show all the users in the database, and a radio box.

But actually, I want to create the form, so that I can add a new user(first name, last name, username, email and password) and then the rest of the fields from the abvoe AddStaffForm.

So question basically boils down to adding fields of userform to the addstaffform.
And then handling them into the views.

Is it doable, or will I have to do it manually?

Can the above model form be extended so that I can first fill in a user detail, and then assign a type to him??

Please let me know, thanks.

Comment: If by type you mean `member_type` then no, any other model, no. You would have to do some javascript for that. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/VSRKu/

Comment: updated, my basic question is to add the fields for user(firstname, lastname, email, username, password etc.) to the above modelform and being able to automagically process the data in a single view. Which creates the OrgStaff, who is basically a user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use two separate forms - `UserForm`, created out of `models.User` & `AddStaffForm` but exclude the 'user' field in the AddStaffForm. Use only ONE submit button for both.

So your template will look like:

```
<form method="post" action="/path/to/wherever">
    {{ user_form }}
    {{ add_staff_form }}
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Then, when the user submits the form, process each form independently in the following order:

1. Process the user form first and save the `user` instance created by the form to the db. if `user_form.is_valid()` is `True`, you can do this by simply doing `user = user_form.save()`
2. Next, process the `AddStaffForm` but pass `commit=False` (i.e. `staff = add_staff_form.save(commit=False)`  since it does not contain the value for the `user` field just yet. Provide the user values using `staff.user = user` and then `staff.save()`

Provided all other fields in the staff form are provided for (i.e. `add_staff_form.is_valid()` is otherwise `True`, this should result in the creation of a new `staff` instance written to db.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: thanks for the answer, had figured http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727564/how-to-create-a-userprofile-form-in-django-with-first-name-last-name-modificati similar manner.